# Can iBeacon communicate with a remote server for publishing messages

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon, beacon

I'm trying to develop a solution, where iBeacon has to be used as an alerting mechanism. This iBeacon has to receive alerts or messages from a remote server and then publish the same to its nearables.

Is this a possible usecase where iBeacon has to receive request from a remote server? As a disclaimer, I new to this technology and let me know if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are approaching this problem from the wrong angle. Essentially you would like to receive a message when you encounter certain iBeacon signals. iBeacons are "dumb" devices, meaning they can only broadcast a data packet, they cannot receive any information and cannot broadcast anything different than the iBeacon protocol packet.

That being said, if you had a remote server that stored these messages, you ask the server what the most recent message is associated with the beacon you have just encountered. That way you can change the messages dynamically on the server based on what you need your user to know.

So essentially, because each beacon can be uniquely identified based on UUID, major, minor, you can store your messages based on this so that you can ensure the user is receiving the correct message when they encounter the beacon by sending these identifiers up to your server in order to retrieve the message.

Comment: Correct! It is important to stress that beacons don't broadcast message strings or communicate them to mobile devices -- they only broadcast a very short numeric identifier.  This identifer can be used to look up a message string in some kind of table (either embedded in the mobile app or in an online database exposed by a web service).  The advantage of the web service is you can change the message on the remote server as described in the question.   The drawback is that the mobile devices must have an internet connection to get the message.  Pre-caching messages helps lessen this drawback.

Comment: Thanks @RDSpinz for the explanation. The site you shared was really helpful.